# Why Cloudinary keeps deleting my images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, heroku, cloudinary

I have a test app: [www.spottedbr.com](http://www.spottedbr.com/)
It's hosted no **heroku** 
and I use this 2 gems:

```
gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"
```

I don't have any visitors yet ( so the app sleeps in heroku ).
But When I decide to upload a thumbnail and a cover image, after some days( or after the app sleep I think? ) the image that I uploaded is no longer available. Can someone here explain me why this happens? Do I need to pay something? What's wrong??

Edit:
I use this method to upload images( from RailsCasts.com ): http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

and I just added the plugin Cloudnary to my app on heroku, nothing more was done.

Comment: do the images disappear every time you deploy a new site?

Comment: Are you sure the images are actually uploaded to cloudinary? Can you please check in the media library and verify that they have been uploaded.

Comment: they wasn't, my problem was on actually applying the service to my app, Thanks anyway for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using something like Amazon S3/Rackspace files with Carrierwave then your uploads will only exist on the dyno that they were uploaded to and only until the dyno is next restarted or deployed to.

You need to look into a persistant file store https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3 or move all your asset storage into Cloudinary which you mention in your post. Details on how to configure it on Heroku are at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudinary